# GSON 2.2.2 can not serialize the type "? extend someInterface"

Tags: java, serialization, gson

Gson 2.2.2 can not serialize the field in Object1.

```
public class Test {

    public static void  main(String[] args){
        Object1 o1 = new Object1();
        List<Interface1> list1 = new ArrayList<Interface1>();
        Interface1 f1 = new InterfaceImp();
        list1.add(f1);
        o1.field = list1;
        System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(o1));
    }
}
interface Interface1{}
class  InterfaceImp implements Interface1{
    public String s = "123";
}
class Object1 {
    public List<? extends Interface1> field ;
}
```

when debuging, I found the method in *TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper* :

```
private Type getRuntimeTypeIfMoreSpecific(Type type, Object value) {
    if (value != null && (type == Object.class || type instanceof TypeVariable<?> || type instanceof Class<?>)) {
       type = value.getClass();
}
    return type;
}
```

do not return the value.getClass(). The arg 'type'(*? extends Interface1*) make the if test be fasle. A bug?

Comment: Um, *what* type would you expect it to return, exactly? You're using a bounded wildcard which means you have no type. You ... can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to specify the generic type you're using in the List

Check this link

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples

For example, for serializing the list:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Interface1>>(){}.getType();
String s = new Gson().toJson(list1, type);
```

Working code (tested)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object1 o1 = new Object1();
    List<Interface1> list1 = new ArrayList<Interface1>();
    Interface1 f1 = new InterfaceImp();
    list1.add(f1);
    list1.add(f1);
    o1.field = list1;

    String s = getGsonWithAdapters().toJson(o1);
    System.out.println(s);
}

public static Gson getGsonWithAdapters() {
    GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
    gb.serializeNulls();
    gb.registerTypeAdapter(Object1.class, new CustomAdapter());
    return gb.create();
}

public static class CustomAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Object1> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Object1 obj, Type type,
            JsonSerializationContext jsc) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        Type t = new TypeToken<List<Interface1>>() {}.getType();
        jsonObject.add("field", new Gson().toJsonTree(obj.field, t));
        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have fixed this problem by using customed adapter, but why do not make the method 'getRuntimeTypeIfMoreSpecific' return the real Type in this case?

Comment: actually I don't know, I have a similar problem and I resolved too with the custom adapter which works always but it requires to add some lines of code by hand... anyway hope my answer helped ;)